# Fast way to Parse and Print a Google Protobuffer

Tags: c++, qt, protocol-buffers

I receive a [Google Protobuffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/) and save it in a [QByteArray](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html). 
Now I parse the received data into the respective protobuff with

```
::proto::dummy * protobuffer; 
QByteArray * ByteArray;

//receive Data
...

protobuffer->ParseFromArray(ByteArray->data(), ByteArray->size);
if(protobuffer->has_XY) /* print it to Log */;
```

Since my protobuffer has several data fields I want to avoid enquirying every entry as showing in the approach above. Is there any fast way to print all of the information of the protobuffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to get a human-readable representation of the protocol buffer, you can call its `DebugString()` (or `ShortDebugString()`) method. You can read more about those methods in the `Message` class documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Message).

Comment: I actually tested `DebugString()` yesterday but did not have any output (empty string). However, today this just works perfectly fine...